# Illegal string offset when display data from array PHP

Tags: php, string, offset

After upgrade server from PHP 5.3 version to 5.6 my application get error like this:

**Illegal string offset 'id'**

This is the part of code where the error exist:

```
foreach($db_table_fields as $key => $value)
{
if($key == 'id')
{
$out .= '<td style="display: none;"><input type="'.$value.'" name="'.$key.'[]" value="'.$row[$key].'"  /></td>';
}
```

I think I know that my variable required an array, but this is string - I still can't fix it. Maybe someone once had such a problem or have idea how fix it?

Thank You in advance for Your help.

Comment: For your HTML value attribute, you try to pull `$row[$key]` - where does `$row` come from?  You probably want `$db_table_fields[$key]`

Comment: `$row` doesn't exist in your code, but you're referencing it as if it's an array.

Comment: skip 5.6 go to 7+